# Given n ranging from $1$ to $100$, find sum of digits equal to half of arithmetic sum of $1$ to $100$

Tags: probability

I have a number sequence from $1$ to $100$.
Given $2$ bins, the numbers are randomly assigned to each bin.

I know the total sum from $1$ to $100$ is $5050$.
Thus, for both bins to have the same sum, each bin must sum up to $2525$.
All the $100$ numbers must belong to either bin.

I know there are a total of $2^{100}$ possible combinations.
How do I find the number of combinations that sum to $2525$ in each bin?

Thank you.

EDIT:
Just to clarify, a bin is just a collection of numbers.
So essentially, I have collection $A$ and collection $B$.
The sum in each collection must be equal and all $100$ numbers must belong to either collection.
Think of them as buckets or whatever is convenient for explanation.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick i believe the OP considers the collections as A and B. And also apparently either A=$\phi$ or B=$\phi$ is valid here.

Comment: Ah yes. bins as in two different collections.

Comment: Hint: try it with a smaller set (i.e. [1..8]). The total sum is 36, so we want a sum of 18 in each collection.

Comment: I tried with 1 to 4. Just no idea if it is easily generalised for larger numbers. Will try 1 to 8 and post back after that.

Comment: Are you sure that you want the number of combinations? Are you not satisfied with for instance the probability that you end up with $2525$ in each bin? Maybe that's easyer (no promis).

Comment: I don't need the entire list of combinations that will give me a sum of 2525 in each bin. So yes, I am satisfied if I can find the probability of having 2525 in each bin.

Comment: Actually you are looking for $2N_{25}$ where $N_{m}$ is the cardinality
of $\left\{ \left(k_{1},\dots,k_{4m}\right)\in\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{4m}\mid\sum_{i=1}^{4m}ik_{i}=m\left(4m+1\right)\right\} $.
Maybe a recursion formula can be found for $N_{m}$. Uptil now I did not succeed.

Comment: I figured it was some form of recursive method. Does that mean it is impossible to find this probability mathematically using pen and paper?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean by that. Finding out a recursive method asks for pen, paper and thinking. I am not in a position to guarantee however that it will be fruitful.

Comment: I have the flexibility to solve this either mathematically by equations or develop a program to calculate it. Both are extremely daunting. Thus I was looking to see if there was any hints that I might be overlooking. Seems to be an extremely time-consuming task to solve though.

Comment: I wish you success and do not exclude that an answer to your question will come up. There are some bright guys here. Hereby I close our conversation.

Comment: Why would finding the probability be easier? You know the total already, $2^{100}$, so the number of combinations is just the probability times that. Unless you are going for an empirical approach to find the approximate probability...

Comment: @Tony You are correct. I was too soon in saying that.

Comment: @lone. If you can develop a program, the recursion $f(n,S) = f(n-1,S)+f(n-1,S-n)$ will do it

Comment: I will give that a try. Hopefully it doesn't end up running out of stack space. Thanks for all the helpful input so far!

Comment: @lone: Regarding Bilou06's recursion: For this problem, dynamic programming (or memoization) is absolutely essential, or else you'll end up repeating a lot of work and likely take years to finish computing (if you don't run out of stack space earlier). Basically, instead of writing a recursive function, you should create a 2D array, fill in some initial entries, and loop through the entries.

Comment: I'm trying that using n=8 first. 256 entries should be much faster than verifying 2^100 entries. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Note: Spreadsheets can be used for double-recursion

Comment: To fill the array, you may use properties such as $n \geq s\implies f(n,s)=f(s,s)$

Comment: Actually, all that is necessary is to set all entries where $S = 0$ to $1$, and all entries where $n = 0$ to $0$. (It doesn't matter what $f(0, 0)$ is set to since it's never used.)

Comment: Set areas where sum=0 to 1, and where n=0 to 0. i'll try to digest all these information. hopefully i can come up with a decent solution. 2^100 is a really huge number to go through.

Comment: You're right, $2^{100}$ is completely beyond any computer's ability to process in a reasonable amount of time. However, you're not actually going through all of them. This is the beauty of algorithms.

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around this whole problem. Thanks a lot for all the guidance. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Actually, what I said about $f(0, 0)$ is incorrect. It must be set to $1$ to work.

Comment: @Bilou06: I got 1731024005948725016633786324. You might be getting integer overflow. I'll make a community wiki post below with my code.

Comment: I got $1.73102 \times 10^{27}$ on my spreadsheet

Comment: You guys are fast!! I'm still trying to figure out how to get the code to work in C++...

Comment: @MarkBennet matches with mine and Tony's. Now next part: what sense do we make of this number?

Comment: I confirm $1.73102×10^{27}$
@Tony, I used $\frac{n(n-1)}2$ in stead of $frac{n(n+1)}4...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the recursion (thanks Bilou06)

$$f(n, S) = f(n - 1, S) + f(n - 1, S - n),$$

we have the following Python code:

```
n = 100
S = 2525

matrix = [[0]*(S+1) for x in range(0, n+1)]

for S in range(0, S+1):
    matrix[0][S] = 0
for n in range(0, n+1):
    matrix[n][0] = 1
for n in range(1, n+1):
    for S in range(S+1):
        matrix[n][S] = matrix[n-1][S] + matrix[n-1][S-n]

print matrix[n][S]
```

You can change the values of `n` and `S` when running the code to verify they work for smaller cases.

Comment: $1731024005948725016633786324$ is a very good answer. Next question: any idea *what* this is? I mean, a proper value in terms of binomial coefficients/power?

Comment: The prime factorization is $2^2 \times 61 \times 1044041 \times 6795097778839840081$. Not sure what this means though.

Comment: I'm also curious to know what the number means. I know if i test with n=4 and S=5, i get 2, which is correct since there are only 2 combinations that sum to 5. What other meanings can the answer have?

Comment: I have a question regarding the values obtained at the final row. At each step, the calculation considers S ways to choose n-1 and S-n ways to choose n-1. What is the significance of the result obtained in the last row? if a n of 3 is used, my last row is [2, 2, 2, 2].

Answer (score 0):

i converted the code to c code. 
however, my code would just hang.

i tried this with a smaller value of n =15.
but my c code produces 5505 instead of the 722 this python code produced.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>  main() 
{ 
 int n=100; 
 double k=2; 
 int min=2525; 
 int rec[100][2525]; //100 row, 2525 column
 int x,y,r,c,str; 
 int po = (int) pow((double) k,n); //2^100

for (r=0;r<n+1;r++) {
    for(c=0;c<min+1;c++)
    {
        rec[r][c]=0;
    } } for (x=0;x<n+1;x++) {
    rec[x][0]=1; }

for (y=0;y<min+1;y++) {
    rec[0][y]=0; }

for (r=1;r<n+1;r++) {
    for(c=0;c<min+1;c++)
    {
        rec[r][c]=rec[r-1][c]+rec[r-1][c-r];
    } }

printf("%d, %d, %d\n",rec[100][2525],r,c); printf("%d", po ); scanf ("%d",str); }
```

Comment: If you expect someone to help you with your code, you could pay attention to make it as readable as possible. What is tt?

Besides, rec[0][0] should be 1, as in he python code

Comment: rec[100][2525] is not a valid statement. If you define "int x[123]" the maximal element you can access is "x[122]".