# If $A=\{n | n \in N, n\le 100\}$ Which number has the most representations as the sum of the elements of a subset of $A$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If $A= \{n | n \in N, n\le 100\} $, which number has the most representations as a sum of the elements of a subset of $A$ and why?
My guess would be $\frac{100.101}{2}$ but I am not sure how it can be proved.

Comment: Do the elements in the sum have to be distinct.  Can you have 1+1+3=5?

Comment: Yes they have to be distinct.

Comment: Then $\frac{100\cdot101}2$ is an awful guess - it can only be represented as $1+2+\ldots+100$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh, well. what I meant to type was half of the sum of the set so $\frac{100\cdot101}{4}$

Comment: Try it with smaller values to see if you get insightt.  Let n <= 5.  6 can be a+b= 6.  That's 5.  And 1+2+3 so that's 6 ways.  You can get some recursion definition I think.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715267/given-n-ranging-from-1-to-100-find-sum-of-digits-equal-to-half-of-arithmetic-su/715326

Comment: The general problem (with 100 replaced by $m$) is discussed at http://oeis.org/A025591 and some of the links there.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a nice proof. But a bit of Python shows that you're right, the unique maximum is achieved by $2525$.

```
import collections
counts = collections.defaultdict(int)

# There is one way to express 0 as a sum of a subset of the empty set.
counts[0] = 1

for element in range(1, 101):
  # Add counts to itself right-shifted by element
  for target in range(len(counts) - 1, -1, -1):
    counts[target + element] += counts[target]

maximum = max(counts.values())
print maximum
print [x for x, count in counts.items() if count == maximum]
```

1731024005948725016633786324
[2525]